# AngularJs ui-router state change listener

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I was trying to implement a listener which could listen to the state change event by doing something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event) {
  if (!AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
    console.log('DENY');
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('login');
  }
  else {
    console.log('ALLOW');
    $state.go('/home');
  }
});
```

But, this won't work as mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2720) that it is deprecated and `transitions` should be used in place of them so I tried something like:

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function() {
  if (!AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
    console.log('DENY');
    return $state.target('login');
  }
  else {
    console.log('ALLOW');
    return $state.target('home');
  }
});
```

This is giving out an error :

```
app.js:21 Error: Too many Transition redirects (20+)
at Transition.run (app.js:18)
at app.js:21
at processQueue (app.js:10)
at app.js:10
at Scope.$eval (app.js:10)
at Scope.$digest (app.js:10)
at Scope.$apply (app.js:10)
at app.js:6
at Object.invoke (app.js:7)
at doBootstrap (app.js:6)StateService._defaultErrorHandler @ app.js:21
```

Any ideas on what might be going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried this [suggested option](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2720#issuecomment-216268572)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are forcing a change of state by doing a

```
return $state.target('home')
```

This causes another transition to fire, and it will come to the same decision and do another

```
return $state.target('home')
```

I think you should not force a state here, just allow it to continue :)

Comment: Thanks for replying, but then where do I do the state change to 'login' if the user is not authenticated when changing a state?

Comment: Where you do a state.go('login') is fine, you don't need to redirect to /home, just let that be, and the problem will go away

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Not tested, but it should work.

```
app.run(function ($state,AuthenticationService, $rootScope) {
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event) {
  if (!AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
    console.log('DENY');
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('login');
  }
  else {
    console.log('ALLOW');
    $state.go('/home');
  }
});  
})
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but it goes into an infinite loop saying `value: Error: transition superseded`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to check current state and you got

> "Too many Transition redirects"

Try something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {
    if (!AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
        console.log('DENY');
        if (toState.name !== 'login') {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('login');
        }
    } else {
        console.log('ALLOW');
        if (toState.name !== 'home') {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('home');
        }
    }
});
```